# Overwriting Flash Drive with ISO File?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, flash

I have a USB flash drive that has an iso file of Ubuntu 18.04 on it. To be honest, I don't really remember how I'd done that, might have been with Rufus on Windows, or with the Startup Disk Creator on Ubuntu.

Anyways, can I now simply overwrite the content of the flash drive (I want an iso file of a newer Ubuntu version)? If yes, do I follow the same steps as described [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview), or are there differences because there is already an iso file on my flash drive. I can currently boot from the flash drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course you can rewrite it with whatever you want. Flash drives are not one-time-use.

The tutorial you linked is the most authoritative/official source so that's a good guide to follow.  There are also tutorials for doing the same on both [Windows](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and [Mac](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos).

The tutorial to [Install Ubuntu Desktop](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop) also includes instructions for creating the installation media using balenaEtcher which is a cross platform utility that works equally on all three operating systems.

Comment: Thanks. So do I understand it correctly that I simply erase the old files from the flash drive, or can I have two iso files on it (and in principle decide upon booting whether to install 18.04 or 20.04)?